# How to add child node in treeview at runtime in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have treeView control in my web page which has three parent nodes `Parent1`, `Parent2`, `Parent3`. Then how i will add the child at runtime.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can add parent and child dynamically by creating the objects of `TreeNode`.
i.e.

```
foreach (TreeNode objTN in TreeView1.Nodes)
{
    if (objTN.Text == "You Parent Name")
        {
            TreeNode child = new TreeNode();
                child.Text = "childText";
                objTN.ChildNodes.Add(child);
    }
}
```

Please refer link [Adding children to a treenode dynamically in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326411/adding-children-to-a-treenode-dynamically-in-c-sharp) for more details.