# How to Attach dynamically different MenuStrips to all fetched Child's child Nodes in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am fetching a database `Records`, so I made 3 `ContextMenuStrip`s. First (`contextmenuestrip1`) added by manually through `c#` properties. Now I fetched database values and made them root nodes, then dynamically add `contextMenuStrip2` to that all root nodes. The Root Nodes contains a child nodes, so I want to bind `contexMenuStrip3` dynamically to the all child nodes. Through both (by front-end or back-end). Can anyone help me here?

I addeed `contextmenurstrip2` to root nodes dynamically through front-end.

The code:

On Form

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BusinessClass bc= new BusinessClass ();
    bc.GetDatabaseList(treeview1);
    int f = treeview1.Nodes[0].Nodes.Count;
    for (int i = 0; i < f; i++)
    {
        treeview1.Nodes[0].Nodes[i].ContextMenuStrip = contextmenustrip2;                              
    }
}
```

On Business Class

```
public void GetDatabaseList(TreeView tn)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(MyConString))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT name from 
sys.databases", con))
        {
            using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    tn.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(dr[0].ToString());
                    //here Node[0] is Manually and this is just 
                    //main heading so I not bind and focus on it.
                }                     
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My expected out is when I select the root node contextmenustrip2 show and when I select `Child` of that selected root node so `contextmenustrip3` show.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding childs to a treenode dynamically in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326411/adding-childs-to-a-treenode-dynamically-in-c-sharp)

Comment: maybe you not get my question

Comment: In `NodeDoubleClick` event add childs nodes to `treeView1.SelectedNode` with the help of link in comment